# Composite numbers $n$, such that every $a$ with $1<a<n-1$ is a witness

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

A Carmichael number $n$ has the property that

$$a^{n-1}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n\ )$$

for every $a$ with $(a,n)=1$.

I wonder, which numbers have the converse property :

> For which composite numbers $n$, every number $a$ with $1<a<n-1$ is a witness ?
>
> That means, for which composite numbers $n$ does $a^{n-1}\neq 1\ (\ mod\ n\ )$
>     hold for every $a=2,3,...,n-3,n-2$ ?

The numbers upto $200$ with this property are :

```
? for(n=2,200,if(isprime(n)==0,gef=1;for(a=2,n-2,if(Mod(a^(n-1),n)==1,gef=0));if
(gef==1,print1(n,"  "))))
4  6  8  9  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26  27  30  32  34  36  38  40  42
44  46  48  50  54  56  58  60  62  64  68  72  74  78  80  81  82  84  86  88
90  92  94  96  98  100  102  104  106  108  110  114  116  118  120  122  126
128  132  134  136  138  140  142  144  146  150  152  156  158  160  162  164
166  168  170  174  178  180  182  184  188  192  194  198  200
?
```

The first few odd composite numbers with this property :

```
? forstep(n=3,2000,2,if(isprime(n)==0,gef=1;for(a=2,n-2,if(Mod(a^(n-1),n)==1,gef
=0));if(gef==1,print1(n,"  "))))
9  27  81  243  729
```

So, from the odd composite numbers, only the powers of $3$ seem to have this property.

The first few even composite numbers, NOT having this property :

```
? forstep(n=2,100,2,if(isprime(n)==0,gef=1;for(a=2,n-2,if(Mod(a^(n-1),n)==1,gef=
0));if(gef==0,print1(n,"  "))))
28  52  66  70  76
```

Comment: Is there a name for a number with this property ?

Comment: Regarding the last list ($28$, $52$, $66$, $70$, $76$, $\ldots$), do you have an idea which number $a$ are the "offenders"?

Comment: @Peter just in case, but probably you already checked it, your sequence seems to be this one at OEIS https://oeis.org/A227180 . Composite numbers $n$ such that $b^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$  implies $b \equiv -1$ or $+1 \pmod n$.

Comment: Useful link indeed! It approves my conjecture about the odd composites and gives an easy criterion for the even composites with the desired property!

Answer (score 2):

For odd $n$, we have the pseudoprime base counting formula:

$$\prod_{p|n} (n-1,p-1)$$

If we want $n$ to have exactly 2 bases to which it is pseudoprime ($\pm 1$), that places significant restrictions on $n$.  If $n$ odd, then both $n-1$ and $p-1$ are even.  Thus there can be only one prime divisor, and $n=p^\alpha$ for some $p$.  But $p-1$ divides $p^\alpha-1$ so $(n-1,p-1)=p-1$.  Thus $p-1=2$ or $p=3$, and every power of 3 is a pseudoprime to 2 bases (excluding 3 itself which is prime).

The formula comes from factoring $n$, and using the CRT and primitive roots.  It can be adapted to even $n$.  But $a^{n-1}\equiv 1(2^\alpha)$ only ever has one root since $n-1$ is odd, and every $a\neq 1$ is of even order modulo $2^\alpha$.  The formula becomes:

$$\prod_{\text{odd}\ p|n} (n-1,p-1)$$

This is $>2$ for exactly the exceptions you list: $28, 52, 66, 70, 76, 112, 124, 130, 140, \dots$.